# Derivative proof

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

This proof is on derivatives. I have no idea where to even begin.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by induction on $n$.

Comment: so you do a base case with 1. then what?

Comment: Everything is set up for the induction with the observations that come after "you may use".

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by induction on $n$. The case $n = 1$ is ease to check. Then, assuming that $$(fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$$ is true, you can use the product rule and the other identity given to prove that $$(fg)^{(n+1)} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} {{n+1} \choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n+1-k)}.$$

---

You want to find an expression for $(fg)^{(n+1)}$, right? Notice that $(fg)^{(n+1)} = ((fg)^{(n)})'$. This way:

$$(fg)^{(n+1)} = ((fg)^{(n)})' = \left(\sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}\right)'$$

and now you use the product rule. Can you go on?

Comment: I guess its just not clicking on how you would use the product rule and the other identity given to prove the above.

Comment: Check my edit. I elaborated a little more on it.

Comment: then I just do what paul did above and that is it?

Comment: Yes. Since he already did everything, try to understand each step he made.

Comment: okay. thank you for your help. it makes sense now looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

**By induction on $n$.**

When $n=1$, $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$. It is clear.

Suppose that $(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^kf^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$ holds. Then

$$(fg)^{(n+1)}=((fg)^{(n)})'=\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^k(f^{(k+1)}g^{(n-k)}+f^{(k)}g^{(n+1-k)})
=\sum_{k=0}^n(C_n^k+C_n^{k-1})f^{(k)}g^{(n+1-k)}+C_n^{0}fg^{(n+1)}+C_n^{n}f^{(n+1)}g=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}C_{n+1}^kf^{(k)}g^{(n+1-k)}.$$